# Recovering 'zero bytes' files

Tags: data-recovery

I had some .mp4 files in an external hdd, that somehow were turned into zero bytes files.
The files are still there, however, their size is zero bytes.

I am on a dual boot system, with both Windows 10 and Ubuntu Linux.

I saw the data with `Wondershare Recoverit`, however, in order to recover them, i have to pay and i think $70 is a very high price.

I tried `Disk Keep` but it did not find them. I tried `Kernel Video Repair`, but it did not work and it asks me to pay. I will not pay for something that did not work in the demo.

My only options left are `PhotoRec` or paying for `Wondershare Recoverit` - though i have concerns on paying such a high price, for something that i do not know if it will work.

All the software i tried were based in Windows. The file format of the hdd is FAT32.

If anyone has some ideas, please help me because i am desperate.

Running `chkdsk f:` gives me:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>chkdsk f:
The type of the file system is FAT32.
Insufficient storage available to create either the shadow copy storage file or other shadow copy data.

Volume INTENSO created 01-Mar-19 8:57 AM
Windows is verifying files and folders...
File and folder verification is complete.

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.
2,929,982,976 KB total disk space.
        1,024 KB in 4 hidden files.
      240,128 KB in 938 folders.
  893,854,720 KB in 13,345 files.
2,035,886,848 KB are available.

      262,144 bytes in each allocation unit.
   11,445,246 total allocation units on disk.
    7,952,683 allocation units available on disk.
```

Comment: The question is off topic in Security SE.

Comment: What’s wrong trying PhotoRec? Also, did you take a bit-wise backup of the drive yet, in case you accidentally overwrite the contents?

Comment: I second photorec

Comment: Open Task Manager and check : Do you have a process named `SYSMWIN`? Run also `chkdsk X:` in the Command prompt to see what it finds (do not fix the errors yet).

Comment: @DanielB The contents are fresh and probably not overwritten. There is nothing wrong with trying PhotoRec. But is it cut out for the job? Disk Drill did not work for example.

Comment: @harrymc No i do not have that process. Chkdsc will not let me because it says the disk is write protected.

Comment: Good - SYSMWIN is the "0-byte virus". Try [these solutions](https://appuals.com/fix-windows-cannot-run-disk-checking-on-this-volume-because-it-is-write-protected/) for the read-only problem, but do not run yet `chkdsk /f`. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc I think i did run the chkdsc with /f before, although it said no errors. Sorry, i ost count, tried so many different things today. All day i am trying to solve this. Mostly i work in linux.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you. I re-run it again. I had different results this time. I updated the question with the log. The files are still '0-bytes' though.

Comment: Try indeed photorec - it supports the [mp4 format](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec). If it doesn't succeed, try also the trial version of [MiniTool Data Recovery](https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery-software/).

Comment: @harrymc I will go fot the second option. I have had a bad experience with photorec, as it filled my entire hdd with deleted data. I don't know how to filter out only the data that i want, so i am afraid i will do something wrong again.

Comment: With MiniTool you can select the files to recover, up to 1 GB with the trial version.

Comment: @user1584421: Any success?

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for your interest. I had no success so i resorted to paying about 65 euros for WonderShare Recoverit.... For videos with total duration no more than 10 minutes... It sucks but what can you do about it? They know people are desperate to get their files back, that's why they put these unreasonable prices.